# Delphi Detect if mouse over form's close button

Tags: forms, delphi, mouseover

I want to detect if user clicked on close button on an inactive form inside my application. How can I detect if mouse hovering on form's close button so I can use that data when form is being closed?

Comment: I mean my application's form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send the Form's window a [`WM_NCHITTEST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618.aspx) message, passing the mouse's screen coordinates in the `lParam` value.  If the return value is `HTCLOSE`, the mouse is over the Close button.

However, just because the mouse is over the Close button does not guarantee that the user actually clicked on the button.  For instance, the user could move the mouse over the button and then type <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> on the keyboard instead (or <kbd>Alt+Space</kbd>, arrow down to the `Close` option, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which invokes the same action as <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd>).

Whether clicking on the Close button, or using a keyboard shortcut, the same [`WM_CLOSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617.aspx) message is sent to the window (triggering the Form's `OnCloseQuery` and `OnClose` events), and it does not report *why* the window is being closed.

If you need to differentiate, you can have your Form handle the [`WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645620.aspx)/[`WM_NCLBUTTONUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645621.aspx) and [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360.aspx) window messages.  When closing the window by clicking on its Close button, `WM_CLOSE` will be preceded by `WM_NCLBUTTON...` with the `wParam` set to `HTCLOSE`.  When closing the window by keyboard shortcuts, `WM_CLOSE` will be preceded by `WM_SYSCOMMAND` with its `wParam` set to `SC_CLOSE`.